# Check if array with objects contains an object in JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, object, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to write a function that will make it easy to know if a specific object key/value is contained within another array with objects.

I've tried indexOf but that doesn't seem to do the trick.
Example:

```
if(data2.indexOf(data1) > 0){
    console.log("Found!");
    return true;
  }else{
    return false;
  }
```

Here is the object:

```
  {
    "movie": {
      "ids": {
        "imdb": "tt2975590"
      }
    }
  }
```

I need a function that can tell me if it's already in another array like this one:

```
[
  {
    "id": 2008588422,
    "type": "movie",
    "movie": {
      "title": "Batman v Superman: Dawn of Justice",
      "year": 2016,
      "ids": {
        "trakt": 129583,
        "slug": "batman-v-superman-dawn-of-justice-2016",
        "imdb": "tt2975590",
        "tmdb": 209112
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 1995814508,
    "type": "movie",
    "movie": {
      "title": "Dirty Grandpa",
      "year": 2016,
      "ids": {
        "trakt": 188691,
        "slug": "dirty-grandpa-2016",
        "imdb": "tt1860213",
        "tmdb": 291870
      }
    }
  }
]
```

In this case it would be and return true. (the movie Batman v Superman has the same imdb id).

Any help? Thanks! :D

Comment: What have you already tried?

Comment: Updated my question with example and better explanation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To clarify you got an [array that contains objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12288820/what-are-the-differences-between-using-json-arrays-vs-json-objects). You should take a look at [`Array.prototype.some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some), which will iterate over an array and return true if true is returned from inside the callback.

```
var search = {
  "movie": {
    "ids": {
      "imdb": "tt2975590"
    }
  }
};

var found = arr.some(function(obj) {
  return obj.movie.ids.imdb == search.movie.ids.imdb;
});
```

Where `arr` is the array of movies.

You can use [dot notation and bracket notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4968406/javascript-property-access-dot-notation-vs-brackets) to access properties in an object, eg: `search.movie` and `search['movie']` will return:

```
{
  "ids": {
    "imdb": "tt2975590"
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you andlrc !! Works perfectly :D

Comment: @webslash I'm glad it worked, now time to read my answer twice, and rewrite it yourself :-) I also linked a few interesting reads.

Comment: Will do! Thanks again for the answer :)